# Issue in magento index management

Tags: magento, indexing, magento-1.8

I am having a client site on Magento CE 1.8.0.0. I am getting this absurd issue with index management.

1. I am turning all indexes to be "update on save"
2. After a few minutes the "Stock Status" Index is automatically set to "Manual".
3. Due this problem whenever I update price of a product, it is not reflecting in the category list page, unless I re-index all the indexes.

Earlier I had the Extendware Extension Installed, but now I have disabled the Extendware Deffered Indexing Extension but the problem still persists.

Can anybody help in this regard.

Comment: How did you disable the extension? I would suggest removing the code completely and seeing if the problem still happens.

Comment: I just removed everything. and the problem still occurs.
Although, I did a small workaround, I created a cron which runs every one minute to set the index mode back to automatic.